# Give a sentiment polarity of a review

Tags: r

I have a review given by a student :

```
The course was interesting, but the professor was so boring.
```

And a sentiment Dataframe which contains all  the sentiment words and their polarity (positive and negative polarity)

```
> sentiment_DF
word  positive-polarity  negative_polarity
interesting  1  0
boring  0  1
pretty  1  0
...
```

I try to do a function with R to determine the polarity of sentiment words of text.
So for this, I extract all the words of the text :

```
# split into words. str_split is in the stringr package
word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')
# sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much
words = unlist(word.list)
```

then,  check for each word in the list if it exist in the sentiment_dataframe and determine its polarity
I try with this code:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- setDT(sentiment_DF)
dt <- melt(sentiment_DF, id.vars = "word")
dt[word == "b" & value > 0, variable]
```

The algorithm :

```
overall_sentiment <- 0
while there is sentiment_word in text do 
   polarity <- get_polarity(sentiment_word)
   overall_sentiment <- overall_sentiment + polarity
end while
```

Can you help me please?

Thank you

**----Edit----**

The basic algorithm changed to this below version :

```
overall_sentiment <- 0
while there is sentiment_word in text do 
   polarity <- get_polarity(sentiment_word)
   if booster_word in context(sentiment_word)
     if negation_word in context(sentiment_word)
       polarity <- polarity/3
     else 
       polarity <- polarity*3
     end if
   end if
  overall_sentiment <- overall_sentiment + polarity
end while

booster_word <- c("more", "very", "too", "much", "completely", "absolutely", "fully", "totally", "definitely", "extremely", "often", "frequently", "enough", "a lot")
negation_word <-c("never", "nothing", "no", "never", "not", "no more")
```

I did a function that extracts the context of the sentiment_word (a sample of 3 words before  a particular word).

```
getContext <- function(text, look_for, pre = 3, post=pre) {
  # create vector of words (anything separated by a space)
  t_vec <- unlist(strsplit(text, '\\s'))

  # find position of matches
  matches <- which(t_vec==look_for)

  # return words before & after if any matches
  if(length(matches) > 0) {
    out <- 
      list(before = ifelse(m-pre < 1, NA, 
                           sapply(matches, function(m) t_vec[(m - pre):(m - 1)])), )

    return(out)
  } else {
    warning('No matches')
  }
}
```

Here is an example :

```
"the course was very interesting, but the professor was too boring."
"Stackoverflow is an intersting place with too interesting people"
```

for the first sentence :

```
"the course was *very interesting*, but the professor was *too boring*."
 (1*3) + (-1*3) = 0
```

the seconde sentence :

```
"Stackoverflow is an *intersting* place with *too interesting* people"
 1+(1*3) = 4
```

My question now id how verify id the context of a word are in the booster_word with R ?
Any idea please?

Thank you

Comment: How exactly the total polarity is calculated ? It's just the sum of the number of occurrences of a word * positive or negative polarity ? I expected the given sentence gave zero...

Comment: I edit my initial post

Comment: Sorry, but your pseudo-code is not clear. what get_polarity actually does ? e.g. in case of word "boring" should return 1 or -1 (since is negative-polarity) ?

Comment: Since it is negative, it must returns -1

Comment: OK, so I need to change my code...

Comment: @digEmAll Hi, I edit my first post , can you have a look please if you have time? thank you

Comment: I don't have the time to change the code now, but I think with a small effort my example can be adapted to your requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can be useful to you :

```
### function to calculate the polarity of sentences
calcPolarity <- function(sentiment_DF,sentences){

  # separate each sentence in words using regular expression 
  # (it returns a list with the words of each sentence)
  sentencesSplitInWords <- regmatches(sentences,gregexpr("[[:word:]]+",sentences,perl=TRUE))

  # pre-allocate the polarity result vector with size = number of sentences
  polarity <- rep.int(0,length(sentencesSplitInWords))

  for(i in 1:length(polarity)){
    # get the i-th sentence words
    wordsOfASentence <- sentencesSplitInWords[[i]]

    # get the rows of sentiment_DF corresponding to the words in the sentence using match
    # N.B. if a word occurs twice, there will be two equal rows 
    # (but I think it's correct since in this way you count its polarity twice)
    subDF <- sentiment_DF[match(wordsOfASentence,sentiment_DF$word,nomatch = 0),]

    # calculate the total polarity of the sentence and store in the vector
    polarity[i] <- sum(subDF$positive.polarity) - sum(subDF$negative.polarity)
  }
  return(polarity)
}
```

Usage :

```
sentiment_DF <- data.frame(word=c('interesting','boring','pretty'),
                           positive.polarity=c(1,0,1),
                           negative.polarity=c(0,1,0))
sentences <- c("The course was interesting, but the professor was so boring.",
               "stackoverflow is an interesting place with interesting people!")
result <- calcPolarity(sentiment_DF,sentences)

# > result
# [1] 0 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably first extract the words. (probably using a regex, to make sure you don't get words like: "interesting,". Store the words of the sentence in a variable called: words_of_sentence.
Then you could just use:

```
dt[word %in% words_of_sentence & value > 0, variable]
```

Comment: Thank you again wligtenberg, the objectif is to extract only the sentiment words that they exist only in the sentiment_dataframe. It is a little complicated

Comment: That is what should happen is this case. No words that are not in your initial sentiment_DF can turn up.